# How to access a JavaScript object got from document.getelementbyId() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have a javascript function and an element in my page:

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
```

JS function:

```
function demo() {
var id = document.getElementById('Button1');
}
```

Now id will contain the object of 'Button1'.

How will I access id through jQuery?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's very simple, you can simply use this for it:

```
$('#Button1') or  $(id)
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery works via CSS-like selectors using the [`jQuery` factory object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) (which is aliased to the shorter, easier to type `$` symbol):

```
var interestingButton = jQuery("#Button1");
// Or alternately
var interestingButton = $("#Button1");
```

If you already *have* a DOM element you can wrap it with the jQuery wrapper by simply [invoking the same factory function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-element):

```
var interestingDOMButton = document.getElementById("Button1");
var interestingjQueryButton = $(interestingDOMButton);
```

Answer (score 2):

Passing javascript `DOM` object to [jQuery( element )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-element) function will return `jQuery` object.

```
jQueryObj = jQuery(id);
```

OR

```
jQueryObj = $(id);
```

It would be better if you directly making jQuery object without creating DOM object using [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

```
jQueryObj = $('#Button1');
```

> For id selectors, jQuery uses the JavaScript function
>   document.getElementById(), which is extremely efficient. When another
>   selector is attached to the id selector, such as h2#pageTitle, jQuery
>   performs an additional check before identifying the element as a
>   match, [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I tried this but I think you just do $(id)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(demo()).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = $('#Button1')
```

Now id will contain the object of 'Button1'.